# Same Origin Policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have read a bit about same origin policy over the last few hours and I understand a little bit of the idea but I have a question about my current setup.

I have a page, we will call, `foo.com/home` and on that page is a link that opens up an iframe with a url of `foo.com/home/bar`.  Now while in the frame of `foo.com/home/bar` if I were to have a hyperlink to say `www.google.com` when clicked can I have it redirect the iframe to Google without breaching the same origin policy? I wouldn't see the harm in that at the least because it would be a simple redirection.

The reason I ask is because with the above set up I am unable to redirect my iframe to `www.google.com`. If this is, in fact, against the same origin policy could someone break it down and explain how? I would understand if I was using the iframe to submit data to another domain but I am simply just trying to get my iframe to redirect to another domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
While

[image]
Or Google in your case.

Possible solution will be using  a local proxy like http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

[image]

This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript.

Comment: Sure, but the charts are a bit misleading because XMLHttpRequest isn't used in this case, and iframes aren't quite as unforgiving as AJAX requests.

Answer (score 5):

It is related to the same origin policy, but it doesn't work only because google.com explicitly prohibits embedding the page to an iframe.

If you look in the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337) you'll see something like this:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

If you try some other page that doesn't have the X-Frame-Options set, like http://nytimes.com,  it will work even though it's not the same domain.