# How to use iframe tag for display width and height

Tags: html, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://desk.zoho.com/portal/myclassboard/kb/articles/how-to-view-event-details-in-the-calendar/">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi friends,

I need how to use the iframe. the above code i wrote display the website in a iframe, but in some cases it work properly and some cases its not working properly, when i change the website link.

In the above case we have change the link to some **https://corp6beta.myclassboard.com/** its working but while put the above link its not working.

I am new to iframe please help me... how to avoid the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346576/same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same question like this before,this might help you [iFrame not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115887/iframe-not-loading-some-urls-but-loading-others/45116052#45116052).

Comment: Kumar Nisit:- how the website display in iframe without the publisher does not allow website to be displayed in a frame..

Comment: It's all about X-frame option.First you have to check for HTTP response header X-Frame-Option of those sites. If its value is "deny or sameorigin", then you can not load those website in the iframes.